# Jquery Croppic Filter image file type

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I use plugin at **http://croppic.net**. Now I want to filter image type (image extension). I mean only image type `(png, jpg, gif)` will appear in dialog choice image to upload.
Please give me some guide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to open up croppic.js and edit the line just after `// CREATE UPLOAD IMG FORM` to read as

`<input type="file" name="img" accept="image/*">`

I don't think this works for IE9 though.